# Set width as percentage of overflowing flexbox container

Tags: css

I am building a Gantt chart using CSS. I calculate the 'offset' of a task from the first date in the header, and the width of the task based on the duration as a percentage of the total range between the dates in the header - see example. This largely works fine except for when there are too many months in the header, and so the overflow starts to scroll, because the percentage of the offset & width are applied to the container width excluding the scrollable portion. How can I fix this so the these values are applied to the actual scrollable width of the container? (Hopefully without using any JS)

In the example, the task should start at 50% (i.e. start of month 7) and run for 25% (i.e. to end of month 9). You can check this by removing the `min-width:300px;`

(Note that the red background will ultimately be transparent)

```css
.container {
   overflow-x: auto;
   width:100%;
   background-color:#eee;
}

.container .months {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
}

.container .months .month {
   min-width:300px;
   padding:5px 10px;
   border:solid 1px black;
   flex: 1 0 0%;
}

.container .bars .bar {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
}

.container .bars .bar .spacer {
   background-color:red;
   
}

.container .bars .bar .task {
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="months">
   <div class="month">Month 1</div>
   <div class="month">Month 2</div>
   <div class="month">Month 3</div>
   <div class="month">Month 4</div>
   <div class="month">Month 5</div>
   <div class="month">Month 6</div>
   <div class="month">Month 7</div>
   <div class="month">Month 8</div>
   <div class="month">Month 9</div>
   <div class="month">Month 10</div>
   <div class="month">Month 11</div>
   <div class="month">Month 12</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bars">
      <div class="bar">
         <span class="spacer" style="width:50%"></span>
         <span class="task" style="width:25%">Task 1</span>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: grid` on the container will fix the issue. The `bars` will be inside a track that has the same size as the `months` element

```css
.container {
   overflow-x: auto;
   display: grid;
   background-color:#eee;
}

.container .months {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
}

.container .months .month {
   min-width:300px;
   padding:5px 10px;
   border:solid 1px black;
   flex: 1 0 0%;
}

.container .bars .bar {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
}

.container .bars .bar .spacer {
   background-color:red;
   
}

.container .bars .bar .task {
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="months">
   <div class="month">Month 1</div>
   <div class="month">Month 2</div>
   <div class="month">Month 3</div>
   <div class="month">Month 4</div>
   <div class="month">Month 5</div>
   <div class="month">Month 6</div>
   <div class="month">Month 7</div>
   <div class="month">Month 8</div>
   <div class="month">Month 9</div>
   <div class="month">Month 10</div>
   <div class="month">Month 11</div>
   <div class="month">Month 12</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bars">
      <div class="bar">
         <span class="spacer" style="width:50%"></span>
         <span class="task" style="width:25%">Task 1</span>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```